# Java time datediff using joda

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

This is my code to calculate deference time with joda time:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import org.joda.time.Interval;
import org.joda.time.Period;

public class DateDiff {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    DateDiff obj = new DateDiff();
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD hh:mm:ss");

    try {

        Date date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse("2015-10-01 20:32:06");
        Date date2 = simpleDateFormat.parse("2015-10-25 00:52:36");

        obj.printDifference(date1, date2);  

        } catch (ParseException e) {
        }
    }

    public void printDifference(Date startDate, Date endDate){

        Interval interval = new Interval(startDate.getTime(), endDate.getTime());
        Period period = interval.toPeriod();

        System.out.printf(
            "%d years, %d months, %d days, %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds%n", 
            period.getYears(), period.getMonths(), period.getDays(),
            period.getHours(), period.getMinutes(), period.getSeconds());
    }
}
```

Here is my reference : http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-time-elapsed-in-days-hours-minutes-seconds/
When I run the code I received:

> 0 years, 0 months, 2 days, 4 hours, 20 minutes, 30 seconds

Can somebody tell me whats wrong with my code?

Comment: `"yyyy-MM-DD hh:mm:ss"` are you sure you know what *DD* means?

Comment: It was the day, am I wrong?

Comment: I've changed the 'DD'to 'dd' but the result remains the same

Comment: `D` --> `Day in year`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've changed the 'DD'to 'dd' but the result remains the same

Well, this is because you ignore something of your [`Period`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html) instance: [the weeks](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html#getWeeks%28%29).

You need to output the instance like this:

```
System.out.printf(
    "%d years, %d months, %d weeks, %d days, %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds%n",
    period.getYears(), period.getMonths(), period.getWeeks(), period.getDays(),
    period.getHours(), period.getMinutes(), period.getSeconds());
```

And you will get:

> 0 years, 0 months, 3 weeks, 2 days, 4 hours, 20 minutes, 30 seconds

and as far as I can see it ... it looks correct.

---

If you don't like to use the weeks here, then you can use a different [`PeriodType`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/PeriodType.html). For example:

```
Period period = interval.toPeriod(PeriodType.yearMonthDayTime());
```

This creates a type which just uses the year, month, day and the time, like you want in your example.

The output is then:

> 0 years, 0 months, 23 days, 4 hours, 20 minutes, 30 seconds

Comment: Don't forget to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) which helped you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You work too much to mix the code of two libraries:

- the old world of `java.util.Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`
- Joda-Time

Better solution is to **use one library only**, here the code for Joda-Time (because the old world does not handle durations at all):

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime ldt1 = LocalDateTime.parse("2015-10-01 20:32:06", f);
LocalDateTime ldt2 = LocalDateTime.parse("2015-10-25 00:52:07", f);
Period p = new Period(ldt1, ldt2, PeriodType.yearMonthDayTime());
String diff = PeriodFormat.wordBased(Locale.ENGLISH).print(p);
System.out.println(diff); // 23 days, 4 hours, 20 minutes and 1 second
```

**Advantages compared with suggested mixed solution:**

- Shorter
- Zero components are suppressed
- Pluralization is handled (for English: "1 second" vs. "2 seconds")
- List pattern support including the word "and"

**General advise about format patterns:**

Please always refer to the [documentation](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) of the library used what format symbols you can use and what they mean. Reading is better than guesswork ;-). There is no unique pattern for all libraries, but "D" really stands for "day-of-year" and "d" for "day-of-month" in both libraries.

Answer (score 0):

For day `d` is small.

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

```
D   Day in year
d   Day in month
```

[SimpleDateFormat doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)